# getOAuthToken returns null when called from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm working on a way to limits some Google Sheets for specific users, with the oAuth specification and AWS API Gateway calls, but i'm facing a problem with the `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` function.

When i'm running the code with the Google Apps Script debugger, everything's fine, `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` returns me a token i can pass to my AWS API. The expected result for now is just to recieve the username.
But if i try to use my function as a macro in a Google Sheets cell, i have the following error `Header:null (line 13)`

Here is the code in the Code.gs file

```js
function HelloW() {
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var headers = {
    'Authorization' : token
  }

  var options = {
    'headers' : headers,
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://###/demo-lambda', options);

  var txt = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(txt);
  var name = json.Message;

  return name;
}
```

And the manifest just in case

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [{
      "menuName": "HelloW",
      "functionName": "HelloW"
    }]
  }
}
```

I've got an error because `token` is null, but i don't understand why it runs well with the debugger, and it doesn't in the Sheets document. I'm missing something and i don't find what.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When run as a macro, services that require authentication are likely not available to the function, hence the reason why `ScriptApp.getAuthToken()` returns null. Check the macro documentation to see what resources you have access to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make calls inside macros that require user authorization.

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask
>   users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)