# Google Script - Send active sheet as PDF to email listed in cell [2019]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I followed the instructions here => [Google Script - Send active sheet as PDF to email listed in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781031/google-script-send-active-sheet-as-pdf-to-email-listed-in-cell), but `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` returns null when called inside google sheets (see => [getOAuthToken returns null when called from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358339/getoauthtoken-returns-null-when-called-from-google-sheets))
Does anyone have any other solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by "returns null when called inside google sheets". Also, how are you running your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only code I have looked up that has worked for me so far, although I would like to figure out how to change the recipient email based on a cell content (in other words, have the script go and fetch the email address from a cell as I am using a vlookup).

https://www.sheetmania.com/2017/11/export-and-email-custom-sheet-to-pdf.html

Comment: Please, post also here the full solution and no only as a link.