# Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.createFile

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

I created a custom script to be run from google sheets which I need to create a file.  The script uses the following code excerpt:

```
  /*
Custom function to call IEXAPI IEXkeystatearningsdate 
@customfunction
*/

function IEXkeystatearningsdate(inputsymbol, stat, version) {

  if (version == "Sandbox" || version == "sandbox")
    var url="https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/"+inputsymbol+"/stats/"+stat+"?token=xyz";
  else
    var url="https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/"+inputsymbol+"/stats/"+stat+"?token=xyz";
  
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);  //Call REST API
  var json=response.getContentText();   
  var data = JSON.parse(json);          //Parse into JSON object
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleString();
  var fn = "IEXkeystatearningsdate_" + n;
  DriveApp.createFile(fn,inputsymbol, MimeType.CSV);
  return (data);
}
```

However, I receive this message:

> "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.createFile. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive (line 20)"

When I run this script directly from the script editor, I **don't** receive this message.

This is my manifest file:

```
{

"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  ],

  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I do not use G-Suite.  I only use google/sheets for my personal use.  The OAuth FAQ says this call should be allowed for personal use.  Can someone help me with what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: First post all your code we need to see how you are authorizing.  Second logout your user and reauthenticate your application im betting you change the scope in your code but have not requested consent of the user again for the new scope.

Comment: Are you running the script `onEdit`?

Comment: @DaImTo - Added full copy of function now.  Regards to logging out, not sure what this means other than signing out of my chrome browser and signing back in.  I did this and error still exists.

Comment: @ziganotschka - not running onEdit.  I did not know about this until I saw your post.

Answer (score 0):

From your error description I can assume that you are running your script on a simple `onEdit` trigger.

### Simple `onEdit` trigger cannot access services that require authorization.

See [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).

For you it means that you can perform to `DriveApp` on simple trigger.

**Solution:**

Use an [Installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.

To do so:

- Rename the function `onEdit()` to something else that is not a key word
- Go on `Edit -> Current project's triggers`
- Click on `+` to create a new trigger
- Specify the funciton to run
- Set `Select event type` to `On edit`

Comment: Per my comment  above, I did not know about triggers.  Let me try this next.

Comment: What is then the alternative of `When I run this script directly from the script editor, I don't receive this message.`? Do you run it as a custom funciton? Or how else do you run it in order to get the error message?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I'm running into new problems now.  Let me resolve them, then I'll come back here with my results.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom functions cannot be used to call services that access personal data:

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data

That, of course, includes `DriveApp`. And it also includes things like [getOAuthToken()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57358339) (it [returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57358339) when called via custom functions), so calling Drive API directly through `UrlFetch` cannot work either.

You should either install an `onEdit` trigger, as [ziganotschka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11599789/ziganotschka) suggested, or call this function through a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) instead of a custom function, so that you're asked for authorization when trying to run it.

#### Reference:

- [Using Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)